# Pushy Integration Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, rebuild

I am attempting to integrate Pushy (https://pushy.me/) into my app to allow for more reliable real-time notifications, in place of GCM.

However, upon attempting to run the app, the error below appears:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/GeneratorBase$1.class
```

Below is my `build.gradle` class:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" // 22.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.myapp2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I have attempted to clean, rebuild, but nothing helps.

How can I alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contacting the support line, I simply needed to prevent duplicate references of the `jackson` library:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
}
```

and changed the dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/pushy-1.0.7.jar')     //** Specified **
}
```

Comment: Pushy engineer here. Our SDK no longer comes bundled with Jackson, so you will no longer have to exclude it manually if it's already bundled with another one of your dependencies. https://pushy.me/docs/android/get-sdk